# How to give a view specific stylesheets in mvc3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid which has "SUBGRID" & "Modal Dialog" functionality. Functionality is working fine but the CSS is not getting applied.

I have multiple stylesheets to be referred, i'm referring almost 6 stylesheet references, But it is not getting applied. instead it says "Link element cannot be nested within element link"

Even if i give the reference for stylesheets in Layout.cshtml. Still the styles are not getting applied.

Please help

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to reference the stylesheets?

Comment: Nick, I'm referring multiple stylesheets as shown above.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. When you view the page, try viewing the source and seeing how it actually rendered your stylesheet links.

Comment: Nick, the stylesheet links are rendering fine in viewsource in body section.